# Beamer - show all bullets in itemize environment but reveal the text for each bullet slide by slide

Tags: beamer, itemize

I would like to show in each of my slides all bullets from the first slide on so that the audiance can see how much information is to be expected on each slide, but the text for each bullet shall come slide by slide.

Unfortunately the `<1->`, `<2->` and so on environment also hides the bullets on the slides before the item gets revealed.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,compress]{beamer} 

\usepackage[english]{babel} 


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> First point
\item<2-> Second point
\item<3-> Third point
\item<4-> and so on
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, for starters can you post an example slide with the bullets? Complete with the preamble, of course. But a personal note in the meantime: If I see the first bullet of a slide, I will know what to reasonably expect depending on the font size of the first item. So the bigger the font, the fewer the items. But in any case, it'd be nice to have a MWE to work on.

Comment: @Alenanno here is my MWE

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'd have to specify the item displays manually:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \mbox{}\onslide<2->{First item}
    \item \mbox{}\onslide<3->{Second item}
    \item \mbox{}\onslide<4->{Last item}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`\mbox{}` is similar to `\leavevmode` so that the `\item` is set. However, the text associated with each item only appears on subsequent slides due to the appropriate overlay specification in `\onslide`.

Comment: This works well, thanks! One just has to be careful to _not_ include "\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}" in the preamble (as I wrongly did...)